# Is there a way to iterate through a two dimensional ArrayList and also invoke the class methods of the objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, iteration

So I am attempting to iterate through a two dimensional ArrayList in Java. Now I have gotten the iteration portion down, however, I can't seem to invoke methods from the object class.

I have checked my spelling to make sure that the class method was spelled correctly. It was. I have also tried iterating through the 2D ArrayList in the same fashion that one would iterate through a 2D Array (Nested For-Loops) while obviously using the ArrayList methods (.get(), .add(), etc.) to select which specific object in the 2D Arraylist that I need.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < layers.size(); i++)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j < layers.get(i).size(); j++)
        {
            layers.get(i).get(j).calculate(); 
            layers.get(i).get(j).activate();
            input3.add(layers.get(i).get(j).getOutput());
        }  


    }
```

The expected results is that the loop will have the objects preform calculations using the invoked class objects for each object in the ArrayList. However, it keeps saying that the methods I'm trying to invoke, which I know are there, cannot be found. I'm not entirely sure how to fix this issue and I can only hope that others have come across this issue and have figured out how to fix it. Thank you in advance.

**Edit/Update**

It should be noted that since this is coming up as an error BlueJ is not letting me compile it.

Now to understand what I mean by "2D ArrayList" here's how I coded it:

```
enter code here
//First lets say we have a few different ArrayLists
ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> list3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
//Now lets say you want to iterate through all of these with only a few 
//lines of code... Put them into another ArrayList
ArrayList<ArrayList> bigList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
```

This is what I mean by a 2D ArrayList. A group of ArrayLists within another ArrayList.

Also the .Calculate() and .Activate() methods take in input from the instantiation of the objects not shown in the code snippet I've presented.

Comment: What is a "2D" array list?  Can you show us the definition?

Comment: Can you add the compile error printed as well as how you create your array lists?

Comment: @Kanjiu It's definitely a compile-time error, probably due to raw type.

Comment: How are you declaring the ArrayList? What types do `calculate` and `activate` expect? What does `getOutput` return? We need more information. Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or we can't help you.

Comment: Stalemate Of Tuning I believe I have made the necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to iterate through ... and also invoke the class
>   methods of the objects?

Yes, of course there is.

Whatever object is stored in a datastructure, you can call its methods. The problem you are facing has two aspects:

First, your `list1`, `list2`, `list3`,... are declared as `ArrayList<Object>`. This means that, whatever you put into the lists, when retrieving the compiler will only know that it's some kind of `Object`. Hence it only allows you to call the methods from `Object` on those elements. This can be worked around by explicit casts, e.g.

```
MyClass element = (MyClass)(layers.get(i).get(j));
element.calculate();
```

However, the better alternative is to use the correct generic type in the first place. Note that `ArrayList<ArrayList>` uses the "raw" type `ArrayList` as the generic type parameter, which is probably not what you want.

So, assuming the elements you store are all of the same type (`MyClass` for example), the clean solution would be like this:

```
ArrayList<MyClass> list1 = ...;

ArrayList<ArrayList<MyClass>> bigList = ...;
```

Now the compiler will know that inside `bigList` there are `ArrayList<MyClass>` objects, and from that, it also knows that inside the elements of `bigList` there are `MyClass` objects. Consequently, it will do the necessary casts automatically for you and you can write `bigList.get(i).get(j).methodOfMyClass(...)`.

If the elements you store in the inner lists do not have a common (super) type, i.e. their only common super type implicitly is `Object`, then you will have no choice than to do the corresponding `instanceof` checks and casts manually.

By the way, since `ArrayList` (indirectly) implements the `Iterable` interface, you can just write

```
for ( ArrayList<MyClass> innerList : bigList ) {
  for ( MyClass element : innerList ) {
    element.methodOfMyClass(...);
  }
}
```

to iterate over all elements of all lists contained in `bigList`.